# Why isn't the code I wrote down working properly?

Tags: python, printing, atom-editor

```
total_price = 0
sneakers = 36.00

total_price += sneakers

print("Total price is" + " " + str(total_price))

print("Total price is" + " " , total_price) << This one doesn`t work properly.
```

Those two statements work like this

```
Total price is 36.0

('Total price is ', 36.0)
```

Why is the first and the second different?

Comment: Are you using Python 2? Because `print(...)` is Python 3 syntax.

Comment: the `,` and the `+`

Comment: That second line of supposed output is *not* what your second `print` produces.

Answer (score 0):

use this line for second print

```
print("Total price is"+" ", total_price, sep='')
```

since print default to `sep=' '` so add extra space while if using `+` you are concatenating text text in this case (same parameter to printf)

`sep` is a like a flag passed to print to tell it what character separate different parameters passed to it

Answer (score 0):

This might have to do specifically on python 2. The print syntax on python 2 is

```py
print ...
```

rather than `print(...)` in python 3.

So the first one have to do with string concatenation. In your first line of code

```py
"Total price is" + " " + str(total_price)
```

This will result in a new string of `"Total price is"`, and `" "`, and `str(total_price)` combined. (i.e. the resulting string is `"Total price is 36.0"`). It is equivalent to

```py
x = "Total price is" + " " + str(total_price)
print x
```

Note that if you insert only a variable between `()` it will not become a tuple, since tuple needs 2 or more variables. So `(x) == x`

The second one

```py
("Total price is" + " " , total_price)
```

is NOT a string concatenation. You used a comma to separate 2 variables. Hence, you inserted two variables and created a tuple, hence results in `('Total price is ', 36.0)`.

To make it clear it is equivalent to:

```py
x = ("Total price is" + " ", total_price) #create a tuple
print x
```

Note that on python 3, this two will print the same output. Since print act more as a function `print(...)` with arguments.

So, it is not not working properly